# Sparse matrix multiplication mod p

Tags: matrix, modular-arithmetic

Let `A` and `B` be sparse matrices with integer coefficients between `0` and `p-1`, with `p` prime. Which is the fastest way to compute their product mod p and obtain another sparse matrix? I'm mainly interested in `p = 2`.

The code `Mod[A.B, p]` returns a sparse matrix, but it may not be "optimal" in the sense that elements that are non-zero in `A.B` but zero in `Mod[A.B, p]` are stored. The code `SparseArray[Mod[A.B, p]]` yields the correct result, but there should be a much faster way.

Comment: Unfortunately `Inner[]` does not give `SparseArray[]` results, so that alternative's out. Are your actual matrices large enough that `SparseArray[Mod[A.B, p]]` is unfeasible?

Comment: My matrices are small (not bigger than 12 x 12), but I need to compute millions of products. I tried using `SparseArray[Mod[A.B, p]]` and it's taking too long.

Comment: Are you doing this conversion after multiplying all those products, or during the multiplication?

Comment: During the multiplication. Every product I make is a product of sparse matrices.

Comment: In my timing experiments, full 12x12 matrix multiplication was faster than sparse 12x12 matrix multiplication.  (I tested with the identify matrix).  There may be no benefit in looking for a sparse solution.